# Wordpress CSS styles not loading

Tags: css, wordpress, hook

> I'm learning to develop a simple WordPress theme from an online course on Udemy. I'm very new to this and I am having difficulty trying to load my stylesheet and fonts.
>
> The following snippet has been placed into my functions.php file

```
// Add StyleSheets
function gymfitness_scripts() {
    // Normalize CSS
    wp_enqueue_style('normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/normalize.css', array(), false, 'screen'); 

    // Google font
    wp_enqueue_style('googlefont', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Raleway:400,700,900|Staatliches&display=swap', array(), false, 'screen');

    // Main Stylesheet
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(), array('normalize', 'googlefont'), false, 'screen');
}

// Hook the StyleSheet
add_action('wp_enque_scripts', 'gymfitness_scripts');
```

> And the following has been placed in my CSS file.

```
/*
Theme name: Gym Fitness
Theme URL: 
Author: Jonathan Cajepe
Author URL: 
Description: Theme designed for the Gym
Version: 1.0
Licence: GNU  General Public Licence v2 or later
Licence URL: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags: CSS Grid, Flexbox ready, mobile first, gym theme
Text Domain: gymfitness
*/

body {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

:root {
    /** Fonts **/
    --mainFont : 'Staatliches', cursive;
    --textFont: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    --secondaryFont : 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 
    /** Colors **/
    --primary : #FF5B00;
    --darkGray: #2F2E2E;
    --lightGray: #EBEBEB;
 
    --white: #ffffff;
    --black: #000000;
 }


body {
    font-family: var(--textFont);
```

> I can't see why my styles and fonts aren't loading. I've been made aware that this online course material is out of date.

> Please see attached image to view my file structure [File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts3vm.png)
>
> I'm just trying to load google fonts and simply change the background to red. [And this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLKzV.png)

Comment: Format your code and add a question so that we know what doesn't work for you.

Comment: Hi, I've edited my original post, I hope I've given a little more context to my issue.

Comment: Remove the Quotes, quotes should only be used if you quote someone else.

Comment: If this is an exact copy of the code you are using, WP won’t attempt to e queue the scripts as there is a spelling error - wp_enque_scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like spell mistake on code for wp_enqueue_script hook and other functions,

Kindly find modified script hook function below

```
// Add StyleSheets
function gymfitness_scripts() {
    // Normalize CSS
    wp_enqueue_style('normalize', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/normalize.css', array(), false, 'all'); 

    // Google font
    wp_enqueue_style('googlefont', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Raleway:400,700,900|Staatliches&display=swap', array(), false, 'all');

    // Main Stylesheet
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('normalize', 'googlefont'), false, 'all');
}

// Hook the StyleSheet
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'gymfitness_scripts');
```

Replace above code and check it,

1. Replaced "wp_enque_scripts" to "wp_enqueue_script" hook
2. Replaced get_stylesheet_directory_uri() to get_stylesheet_uri() function in your code.
3. Replaced last argument of wp_enqueue_style function to "all" instead of "screen"

Comment: Thank you all for the help! I will endeavor to read my code carefully for syntax errors. This worked perfectly!